# Check if signed cookie exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, cookies

I have a controller from which I create a cookie with information about a game I'm developing. The problem I'm having is that the value changes when I use another action inside that controller.

This is my controller:

```
def new
        @videos = Video.order("RANDOM()").limit(2)
        if !cookies.signed[:game]
                cookies.signed[:game] = {
                    :value => @videos,
                    :domain => 'localhost',
                    :secure => !(Rails.env.test? || Rails.env.development?)
                }
        end
    end

    def start_game
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
        end
    end
```

start_game.erb.js

```
console.log('<%= cookies.signed[:game].first.titel %>') # This should print out the same value but it doesn't do that.
```

new.html.erb

```
...
<%= button_to "game", { :action => "start_game" }, { :remote => true, :form_class => "test_button" } %>
```

Can I check whetever a signed cookie exists or not?

Answer (score 0):

The thing that you are storing isn't an array of videos but an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, in a nutshell an unevaluated query. Instead you want to execute the query in the `new` action and store the results.

The easiest way is to instead write

```
@videos = Video.order("RANDOM()").limit(2).all
```